# What is the divisor of the global rational section $1/x_0$ of O(-1) on P1?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am getting positive $(0:1)$, but the notes I am reading say negative $(0:1)$. What is the correct answer? To compute this I am computing the local trivializations on a cover and computing the order of the resulting rational function. I am using $1/x_1$ tensor $x_0 / x_1$ on the other chart, which agrees on the overlap.

Here is the computation I am trying to do (copied from my comment below):

I am thinking of $1/x_0$ as $1/x_0 \otimes 1 \in \Gamma(D_{+}(x_0), O(-1) \otimes K(X))$. Then I make the following manipulations in $D_{+}(x_0x_1)$: $1/x_0 \otimes 1 = 1/x_0 \otimes x_1 / x_1 = 1/x_1 \otimes x_0 / x_1$. The latter identifies defines an element of the tensored sheaf over $D_{+}(x_1)$, and a choice of local trivialization (multiplying by $x_1$), gives a rational function with 0 at $[0:1]$ and no poles on that chart.

Comment: What kind of background do you have? Maybe that's too broad: how are you thinking about $\mathcal{O}(1)$? I don't really follow your explanation. The more you can say in that regard, the better, I think. I don't know where this tensor is coming from, for example.

Comment: @Hoot  I am thinking of global rational sections as the sheaf obtained from O(-1) by tensoring with the constant sheaf of rational functions. The equation 1/x_0 is defining a rational section on the patch where x_0 is not zero, and I am lifting that to a compatible section on the other one. For each of these sections over a local trivialization, I am identifying the section with a rational function and computing the orders of that rational function. I am working out of Gathmanns lecture notes.

Comment: @AreaMan How are you lifting $1/x_0$ to the other one?  Can you clarify this?  One can't lift $1/x_0 \in \Gamma(D_{+}(x_0 x_1), \mathscr{O}(-1))$ to $\Gamma(D_{+}(x_1), \mathscr{O}(-1))$.

Comment: @user0206 Here is what I am trying to do. It is being lifted in the tensor product sheaf with the sheaf of rational functions. I am thinking of $1/x_0$ as $1/x_0 \otimes 1 \in \Gamma(D_{+}(x_0), O(-1) \otimes K(X))$. Then I make the following manipulations in $D_{+}(x_0x_1)$: $1/x_0 \otimes 1 = 1/x_0 \otimes x_1 / x_1 = 1/x_1 \otimes x_0 / x_1$. The latter identifies defines an element of the tensored sheaf over $D_{+}(x_1)$, and a choice of local trivialization (multiplying by $x_1$), gives a rational function with 0 at $[0:1]$ and no poles on that chart.

Comment: @AreaMan Sorry I'm not understanding how $1/x_0 \otimes x_1/x_1 = 1/x_1 \otimes x_0/x_1$ over $D_{+}(x_0x_1)$.  One trivialization of $\mathscr{O}(-1)$ over $D_{+}(x_0 x_1)$ is "multiplication by $x_0$" and under this isomorphism $\mathscr{O}(-1) \otimes K(X) \cong K(X)$ (over $D_{+}(x_0x_1))$ $1/x_0 \otimes x_1/x_1$ goes to $1$ whereas $1/x_1 \otimes x_0/x_1$ goes to $(x_0/x_1)^2 \in K_X$

Comment: @user0206 You may be right - I was thinking that that manipulation was justified because in the ring over which we are tensoring $x_0$ and $x_1$ are invertible... however, I may be getting $1/x_0$ as a generator of the line bundle and $1/x_0$ as an element of the sheaf of regular functions confused... I think that is my mistake!

Comment: @user0206 What do you think? Your computation shows that there was something wrong with my reasoning, and I think I have identified it... let me try this computation again.

Comment: @user0206 Okay, now I think I can do it correctly: In the first trivialization, $1/x \otimes 1$ is sent to $1$, which is sent to $x_1 / x_0$ via the transition map. On the second chart $(x_1 \not = 0$), this now pulls back to the section $1/x_1 \otimes x_1 / x_0$, which has divisor $-[0:1]$. That is the correct answer. Do you think my work is justified?

Comment: @AreaMan That certainly works now.  Verified.